# Allow a custom Attribute only on specific type

Tags: c#, .net, compiler-construction, attributes

Is there a way to force the compiler to restrict the usage of a custom attribute to be used only on specific **property** types like int, short, string (all the primitive types)?
similar to the [AttributeUsageAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.attributeusageattribute%28v=vs.95%29.aspx)'s ValidOn-[AttributeTargets](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.attributetargets%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) enumeration.

Comment: No, this isn't possible.  The most you could do is write a unit test that uses reflection and validates its usage.  But nothing in the compiler will do this.

Comment: also; you can't add attributes to classes outside your control *anyway* - so you can't add attributes to `int` or `string`. Do you mean "only to properties that *are* `int` or `string`" ? if so, the answer is still "no" ;p

Comment: @MarcGravell ofcourse I ment int, string properties and not changing the int class itself, But I'll edit. thanks for the answer.

Comment: Some good, workable answers have been given on this duplicate which was asked just 15 days later: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8574275/c-sharp-attribute-usage-only-allow-attributes-on-a-property-with-specific-data

Answer (score 36, accepted):

No, you can't, basically. You can limit it to `struct` vs `class` vs `interface`, that is about it. Plus: you can't add attributes to types outside your code anyway (except for via `TypeDescriptor`, which isn't the same).

Answer (score 22):

You can run this unit test to check it.

First, declare validation attribute PropertyType:

```
  [AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Class)]
    // [JetBrains.Annotations.BaseTypeRequired(typeof(Attribute))] uncomment if you use JetBrains.Annotations
    public class PropertyTypeAttribute : Attribute
    {
        public Type[] Types { get; private set; }

        public PropertyTypeAttribute(params Type[] types)
        {
            Types = types;
        }
    }
```

Create unit test:

```
 [TestClass]
    public class TestPropertyType 
    {
        public static Type GetNullableUnderlying(Type nullableType)
        {
            return Nullable.GetUnderlyingType(nullableType) ?? nullableType;
        }

        [TestMethod]
        public void Test_PropertyType()
        {
            var allTypes = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies().SelectMany(a => a.GetTypes());
            var allPropertyInfos = allTypes.SelectMany(a => a.GetProperties()).ToArray();

            foreach (var propertyInfo in allPropertyInfos)
            {
                var propertyType = GetNullableUnderlying(propertyInfo.PropertyType);
                foreach (var attribute in propertyInfo.GetCustomAttributes(true))
                {
                    var attributes = attribute.GetType().GetCustomAttributes(true).OfType<PropertyTypeAttribute>();
                    foreach (var propertyTypeAttr in attributes)
                        if (!propertyTypeAttr.Types.Contains(propertyType))
                            throw new Exception(string.Format(
                                "Property '{0}.{1}' has invalid type: '{2}'. Allowed types for attribute '{3}': {4}",
                                propertyInfo.DeclaringType,
                                propertyInfo.Name,
                                propertyInfo.PropertyType,
                                attribute.GetType(),
                                string.Join(",", propertyTypeAttr.Types.Select(x => "'" + x.ToString() + "'"))));
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Your attribute, for example allow only decimal property types:

```
 [AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Property)]
    [PropertyType(typeof(decimal))]
    public class PriceAttribute : Attribute
    {

    }
```

Example model:

```
public class TestModel  
{
    [Price]
    public decimal Price1 { get; set; } // ok

    [Price]
    public double Price2 { get; set; } // error
}
```

Answer (score 5):

The code below will return an error if the attribute was placed on a property/field that is not List of string.

The line `if (!(value is List<string> list))` may be a C#6 or 7 feature.

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Property |
                AttributeTargets.Field, AllowMultiple = false)]
public sealed class RequiredStringListAttribute : ValidationAttribute
{
    protected override ValidationResult IsValid(object value, ValidationContext context)
    {
        if (!(value is List<string> list))
            return new ValidationResult($"The required attrribute must be of type List<string>");

        bool valid = false;
        foreach (var item in list)
        {
            if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(item))
                valid = true;
        }

        return valid
            ? ValidationResult.Success
            : new ValidationResult($"This field is required"); ;
    }

}
```

Comment: what is a `ValidationAttribute`?

Comment: This forces validation. works in conjunction with the ModelState

Comment: hm I don't have such a type (Unity 2019 with .Net 4.6)

Comment: @derHugo add `Assembly location: C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.dll` and namespace `using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;`

Answer (score 4):

You could write code yourself to enforce correct use of your attribute class, but that's as much as you can do.

Comment: side note: an attribute has no access to it's own context, so any check here would have to be in the reflection code that queries for the attribute

Comment: I wrote a unit test (NUnit) once that used Cecil to verify my "allowable" attribute usages.

Answer (score 0):

The way I am doing this is following:

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Property)]
public class SomeValidationAttribute : ValidationAttribute
{
    protected override ValidationResult IsValid(object value, ValidationContext validationContext)
    {
        if (value is not string stringToValidate)
        {
            throw new AttributeValueIsNotStringException(validationContext.DisplayName, validationContext.ObjectType.Name);
        }

        // validationContext.DisplayName is name of property, where validation attribut was used.
        // validationContext.ObjectType.Name is name of class, in which the property is placed to instantly identify, where is the error.
        
        //Some validation here.

        return ValidationResult.Success;
    }
}
```

And exception look like this:

```
public class AttributeValueIsNotStringException : Exception
{
    public AttributeValueIsNotStringException(string propertyName, string className) : base(CreateMessage(propertyName, className))
    {

    }

    private static string CreateMessage(string propertyName, string className)
    {
        return $"Validation attribute cannot be used for property: \"{propertyName}\" in class: \"{className}\" because it's type is not string. Use it only for string properties.";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For primitive and sealed types, you are sadly out of luck.

However, you can indeed limit the use (and visibility) of an attribute to a type hierarchy, by declaring the attribute as an inner class, with protected or internal visibility.

There are, of course, various limits and corner cases here, but *it is possible*, and probably for a wide variety of use cases.

Internal visibility can allow you to access these fields from other assemblies if you make them visible to these assemblies.

Here is an example of simple automatic validation-time property binding attribute. Tested in Unity 2023.1.12f1.

```cs
using System;
using System.Reflection;
using UnityEngine;

namespace Tiger.Attributes
{
    public class AutoBehaviour : MonoBehaviour
    {
        [AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Field)]
        protected class AutoAttribute : PropertyAttribute { }
        
        private void OnValidate()
        {
            var object_fields = GetType().GetFields(BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.NonPublic);
            foreach (var field_info in object_fields)
            {
                if (Attribute.GetCustomAttribute(field_info, typeof(AutoAttribute)) is not AutoAttribute) continue;

                var value = GetComponent(field_info.FieldType);
                field_info.SetValue(this, value);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Usage is straightforward, for example, if you attach this script component to a Cube primitive gameobject, it will automatically look up and serialize the appropriate components.

```cs
using Tiger.Attributes;
using UnityEngine;

namespace Jovian
{
    public class TestBehaviour : AutoBehaviour
    {
        [Auto] public MeshFilter meshFilter;
        [Auto] public MeshRenderer meshRenderer;
        
        // Start is called before the first frame update
        private void Start()
        {
        
        }

        // Update is called once per frame
        private void Update()
        {
        
        }
    }
}
```