# C# attribute usage: only allow attributes on a property with specific data type

Tags: c#, custom-attributes

I've created a few attributes for properties. now I want to limit these attributes to properties with a certain data type? the idea is, a compiler error will be thrown if it is assign to a different type. is this possible?

if not, then I guess i'll have to check it on runtime.

Comment: Possible Duplicate [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4959863/how-to-make-net-attribute-only-valid-on-certain-types](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4959863/how-to-make-net-attribute-only-valid-on-certain-types)

Comment: I don't think that's a duplicate. that's for applying attributes to a class. this is for properties with a certain type.

Comment: but the fate looks the same :(

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You could write a custom [FxCop/ Code Analysis](http://blog.tatham.oddie.com.au/2010/01/06/custom-code-analysis-rules-in-vs2010-and-how-to-make-them-run-in-fxcop-and-vs2008-too/) rule to check for this.

FxCop is integrated in VS 2010 under the name "Code Analyis", you can change the ruleset in the project properties.

Comment: Thank you, both answers are good and possible solutions. I might go for CA since that's what we use here. i know its probably a bad thing but unit test are not used in our team!

Comment: @Mel FxCop / Code Analysis is absolutely a good option, too.

Answer (score 5):

No, this is not possible.

A good workaround is to build a *unit test* which will traverse all classes, their properties and check for this additional applicability criteria. It's not that comfortable as a compile-time error message, but will serve the purpose. In case you have some kind of build automation infrastructure, the quality assurance level will be the same in practice.